# Best way to Duplicate a Laptop's Hard Drive One-to-One

Tags: windows-7, backup, ubuntu-9.10, restore, multi-boot

I have a Lenovo X61 Tablet computer, with a plain SATA drive inside. I have windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10 dual booting on the computer. I want to back up both of these OS's, and their special partitions (Windows 7 has one, and of course the Linux Swap).

I want a one-to-one backup, all of my mission critical data is already backed up, but I would like to get a snapshot, and store it on a larger file server at home for quick recovery. What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/):

> You're probably familiar with the
>   popular proprietary commercial package
>   Norton Ghost®, and its OpenSource
>   counterpart, Partition Image. The
>   problem with these software packages
>   is that it takes a lot of time to
>   massively clone systems to many
>   computers. You've probably also heard
>   of Symantec's solution to this
>   problem, Symantec Ghost Corporate
>   Edition® with multicasting. Well, now
>   there is an OpenSource clone system
>   (OCS) solution called Clonezilla with
>   unicasting and multicasting!
>
> Clonezilla, based on DRBL, Partition
>   Image, ntfsclone, partclone, and
>   udpcast, allows you to do bare metal
>   backup and recovery. Two types of
>   Clonezilla are available, Clonezilla
>   live and Clonezilla SE (server
>   edition). Clonezilla live is suitable
>   for single machine backup and restore.
>   While Clonezilla SE is for massive
>   deployment, it can clone many (40
>   plus!) computers simultaneously.
>   Clonezilla saves and restores only
>   used blocks in the harddisk. This
>   increases the clone efficiency. At the
>   NCHC's Classroom C, Clonezilla SE was
>   used to clone 41 computers
>   simultaneously. It took only about 10
>   minutes to clone a 5.6 GBytes system
>   image to all 41 computers via
>   multicasting!
>
> **Features of Clonezilla**
>
> - Free (GPL) Software.
> - Filesystem
>     supported: ext2, ext3, ext4, reiserfs,
>     xfs, jfs of GNU/Linux, FAT, NTFS of MS
>     Windows, and HFS+ of Mac OS. Therefore
>     you can clone GNU/Linux, MS windows
>     and Intel-based Mac OS, no matter it's
>     32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x86-64) OS.
>     For these file systems, only used
>     blocks in partition are saved and
>     restored. For unsupported file system,
>     sector-to-sector copy is done by dd in
>     Clonezilla.
> - LVM2 (LVM version 1 is
>     not) under GNU/Linux is supported.
> - Multicast is supported in Clonezilla
>     SE, which is suitable for massively
>     clone. You can also remotely use it to
>     save or restore a bunch of computers
>     if PXE and Wake-on-LAN are supported
>     in your clients.
> - Based on Partimage,
>     ntfsclone, partclone, and dd to clone
>     partition. However, clonezilla,
>     containing some other programs, can
>     save and restore not only partitions,
>     but also a whole disk.
> - By using
>     another free software drbl-winroll,
>     which is also developed by us, the
>     hostname, group, and SID of cloned MS
>     windows machine can be automatically
>     changed.

Using Clonezilla Live, you can create a LiveCD/USB drive that you boot to, and then image the partitions or the whole disk.

Comment: +1, I've used Clonezilla and it works great. It's a bit hard in the begining to try to do what you're trying to do since it's not graphical but it works great.

Comment: "Back in my day we had no stinking GUI!" lol, not a huge problem really. Forgot clonezilla existed, and this is what I want. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of luck using [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm).

[image: screenshot]

It works on computers Windows XP and up, including Windows 7 (has to be run as an administrator).

> DriveImage XML is an easy to use and reliable program for imaging and
>   backing up partitions and logical
>   drives.
>
> Image creation uses Microsoft's Volume
>   Shadow Services (VSS), allowing you to
>   create safe "hot images" even from
>   drives currently in use. Images are
>   stored in XML files, allowing you to
>   process them with 3rd party tools.
>   Never again be stuck with a useless
>   backup! Restore images to drives
>   without having to reboot. DriveImage
>   XML is now faster than ever, offering
>   two different compression levels.
>
> DriveImage XML runs under Windows XP,
>   Windows Server 2003, Vista and Windows
>   7 only. The program will backup, image
>   and restore drives formatted with FAT
>   12, 16, 32 and NTFS.

There is one caveat, however - it is Windows-only, so you would have to run the backup/image creation from your Windows partition. I *think* it should back up the whole drive, but I am not entirely sure, as I've never tried it on a multi-boot setup.

From [their FAQ](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage_faq.htm#os):

> With the software installed on a PC,
>   supported file systems are Windows XP,
>   Windows Media Center, Windows Server
>   2003, Vista, and Windows 7. However
>   you can create a BartPE CD with our
>   software on it and boot from any of
>   the Windows 9x or Windows 2000
>   machines and back them up as well.

It can even restore an image to a larger harddrive - I've used it to move an existing system to a larger harddrive with no problems at all.

Comment: Does this support Linux File systems such as EXT4 and Linux swap? The website led itself to appear to be Windows only.

Comment: I updated my answer - honestly, I'm not entirely sure if DriveImage XML would even see the other partitions or not. I've never used it on a multiboot computer, and I couldn't find any information on that or any other people who have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several Free one's for Windows, Ping is for just about any file system or OS.

[Macrium Reflect Free](http://majorgeeks.com/Macrium_Reflect_FREE_Edition_d6034.html)

[Easeus Todo Backup](http://majorgeeks.com/EASEUS_Todo_Backup_Free_Edition_d6195.html)

[Paragon Backup and Recovery](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/features.html)

[Drive Snapshot](http://www.drivesnapshot.de/en/index.htm)

[Ping](http://ping.windowsdream.com/)