# Replace 60GB solid state drive with a higher capacity one

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move smaller hard drive to partition on a larger hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/120426/move-smaller-hard-drive-to-partition-on-a-larger-hard-drive)
>   [restore a smaller hard drive 320GB image to a larger harddrive 1TB](https://superuser.com/questions/306820/restore-a-smaller-hard-drive-320gb-image-to-a-larger-harddrive-1tb)

I have a 60 GB solid state hard drive on my desktop, running Windows 7.  It's working great, but it's getting frustrating to always be running out of space. Now that prices are dropping, I'm thinking of upgrading it.

What is the procedure to upgrade my solid state hard drive to a higher capacity solid state hard drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Purchase a cheap USB/SATA 2.5" drive enclosure when you get your
   SSD.  You can get one for around $10 US at most online retailers.
2. Put your new drive in the enclosure.
3. Download the ISO of [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start), since it has both [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) included.
4. Burn a disc from the ISO
5. Connect the drive enclosure to the computer.
6. Boot to this disc.
7. Use Clonezilla to clone the old drive onto the new one.
8. Use GParted to expand the partition on the new drive to encompass the additional space left untouched by the cloning process.  Apply any changes.  **NOTE** some people have had issues with resizing Vista and Windows 7 boot partitions with GParted, so feel free to skip this step until you have booted to the new drive.  Expand the partition from Drive management within Windows if you want to take the safe route.
9. Shut down, and replace the old drive with the new drive.
10. Boot to new drive, right where you left off with old system intact.

Comment: It is recommended **not** to use GParted to expand Windows (and generally NTFS) partitions if possible - do it from within Windows, less chance of destroying the partition. Of course, if it's just an image that can be restored again, it doesn't really matter :P

Comment: @Bob.  I have never had an issue expanding NTFS partitions with GParted.  But I'll edit the answer just for you.

Comment: I ended up following your instructions exactly, even using GParted and it all worked great.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @mruboy Excellent!  I keep a copy of Parted Magic handy all the time, not only for this, but sometimes just for the OS.  Glad it worked for you.