# Can I add SSD in addition to existing HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, msata

My laptop configuration is (Model - 902143_1_E2E33AV, [HP ENVY TouchSmart 15t-j100 Quad Edition CTO Notebook PC](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-envy-touchsmart-15-j100-quad-edition-notebook-pc-series/6521366/model/6521368/manuals) (ENERGY STAR)) [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03943414)

HP ENVY 15t Quad TouchSmart

- 4th generation Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ Processor
- NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GT 740M Graphics with 2048MB of dedicated video memory
- 15.6-inch diagonal Full HD BrightView LED-backlit Display (1920x1080)
- 16GB DDR3 System Memory (2 Dimm)
- 1TB 5400 rpm Hard Drive

Is it possible to add SSD inaddition to the HDD that I already have with this model (appreciate if you can provide a link to any video tutorial for reference to install the SSD) ? I would like to keep the HDD just for storing data backup keeping my SSD for running OS and to keep my day to day files.

Is there any limitation on how much SSD capacity/storage that this laptop can support ?

Also, i noticed different types of SSD like 2.5"/M2.SATA/MSATA, can this model support any of this?

UPDATE:

```
DISKPART> list disk
Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
--------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
Disk 0    Online          931 GB    20 GB        *
```

TIA

Comment: Take a look at this post, there is a link to the "HP ENVY 15 Notebook PC and HP ENVY TouchSmart 15 Notebook PC Maintenance and Service Guide". It should help you a bit: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/Upgrading-to-SSD-on-HP-ENVY-15t-j100-Quad-Edition/td-p/3542337 page 42

Comment: There I see that it has an mSATA SSD slot and place for a HDD. Maybe you can replace the mSATA with one along these lines "Samsung MZ-M6E500BW 860 EVO - 500GB". I am not 100% certain, but I think you might be in luck.

Comment: On the other hand, this slot might be only usable for a small mSATA to be used as a cache and not a real storage device. Sorry, can't help.

Comment: @raga, please click on the grey  (x) on the above comment to clear it away. Comments pile up until there's no room to see them. Also, which OS are you using? Do you know if the HDD is has an MBR or a GPT partition table? If you have Windows, run `diskpart` in a Command Prompt window then `list disk` and make a screenshot, then `exit` to leave diskpart. Upload the screenshot to http://imgur.com , get the link, and add it to the original post. . Please [edit] the original post to advise.

Answer (score 1):

The MSATA SSD is limited here to 24GB, and there is no M.2 slot for larger/faster SSDs, either SATA or PCIe-NVMe. Using RAM to cache for an HDD requires a newer chipset than this laptop has, for Intel Optane memory or equivalent.

Since your PC has an Intel CPU, the matching BIOS used by HP allows you to  replace the HDD (shown on page 19 of the [repair manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03943414) as item 22 and page 26 as item 2) with a [2.5" wide SSD no thicker than 7mm](https://www.google.com/search?q=7mm%20SATA%20SSD), since you cannot install an M.2 drive and MSATA is a waste of time and money. The installation procedure is show on pages 46-48 of the same manual. You will be very glad you did.

[Buy More](https://express.google.com/u/0/product/3742292416698628462_15490050464220544665_125181302) has a 1TB drive for $135; 2TB and larger SSDs are available but are [disproportionately more spendy](https://www.google.com/search?q=7mm%20SATA%20SSD%202TB), and you can only fit one drive in the enclosure. Also, if you clone your original drive, and it uses an MBR partition table, there's a 2TB cap on partition size (though you could have multiple partitions); if you use GPT partitioning drives have a much larger limit, several orders of magnitude larger, depending on which OS and partitioning you use. External drives go through USB and therefore will be much slower than the 6Gb/sec SATA III speed.

You will also need an external USB drive enclosure to copy your data onto the new SSD by [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) ([how-to link](https://win10faq.com/how-to-clone-windows-10-with-clonezilla/)) or other means. [This article](https://superuser.com/questions/429268/replace-60gb-solid-state-drive-with-a-higher-capacity-one/429271#429271) explains the process as well.

Comment: Did you read the part of the question where they ask: “…appreciate if you can provide a link to any video tutorial for reference to install the SSD…” How do you feel about that?

Comment: Well, I am being a tad sarcastic. This user clearly wants us (the community here) to do all the work for them. That is really not what this site is about. And since they haven’t commented here on your answer yet I thought I would plant the idea in your head that maybe you are falling into a codependency hole. Your advice is solid, but this question has all the signs of something we should not be supporting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment K7AAY. JakeGould, I didn't meant to the community to do all work, Infact i did google about it and found countless videos about installation, however not sure which one is right for the model that i have, thinking that experts may guide me to the right one.